# Make a Web page only accessible from a specific program

Tags: php, web

So my question is quite simple: I have a hosted PHP website and I'm building a program with a web browser on the window to open the site inside.
Is there a way to make the website only accessible from this program? I mean, if someone opens it from another browser (chrome, opera...) it will not open.
Thank you a lot, I appreciate your help

Comment: There is *always* a way.

Comment: It *answered* your *question*, "Is there a way to make the website only accessible from this program?" Other than that your post is quite broad.

Comment: How secure and reliable does this need to be?  There are significant differences between discouraging users from getting around this versus, say, needing to protect confidential data.

Comment: yes, I need to protect my data, so I need it to be secured somewhat. thanks

Comment: You can use custom header with some checksum and lifetime, for example: `My-super-app: '+md5('some_salt'.time())+':'+time();` . I'm sure browser can't hack your checksum algorithm :) But people can :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you may try to create a custom UserAgent string for your aplication and then, check it on your PHP code if the requesting UserAgent is the same as your app UserAgent.

Comment: How secure is that? Is it easy to find out my User Agent string and simulate it from another app? thank you.

Comment: It's not very secure. If your app uses a non-secure external network or access another website wich is not yours, then someone could easily sniff your custom user agent string and simulate it from another app.

Answer (score 0):

I mean something like that...

*notice: any validation and sanitization of incoming data skipped*

> App-side example (it doesn't matter what language you use):

```
<?php

define('SECURE_SALT', '123456');

$t = microtime(true);
$c = curl_init();
$o = array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://my.awesome.site',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('MY-SUPER-APP: '.md5(SECURE_SALT.$t).':'.$t,
);
$r = curl_exec($c);
print_r($r);
```

or even like this:

```
curl -H 'MY-SUPER-APP: 1dcf5ccf8a97d2ffbbacb7bc9e23d0b4:1455130639.1448' http://my.awesome.site
```

> Server-side example:

```
<?php

define('SECURE_SALT', '123456');
define('CHECK_DIFF', 600); // seconds

$now = microtime(true);
$head = $_SERVER['HTTP_MY_SUPER_APP'];
list($hash, $time) = explode(':',$head);
$checkHash = md5(SECURE_SALT.$time);
if (($now - $time) < CHECK_DIFF) {
    if ($hash == $checkHash) {
        // hooray.. our application detected
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: @MrNacer2007, np, you can apply hash calculation inside User-Agent header too :)

Answer (score -2):

Here's how I do it: I create an orphan web page with a weird link (for example: `booboo123_99999.yoursite.com/setitweird444444444.php`), so nobody will know the link but you. You might also deactivate showing the source code from the app browser.

Comment: Security through obscurity isn't a bad thing if it isn't the only layer of protection. By itself, though, this is not a safe solution.